# Validating the scanf entry

Tags: c, validation, scanf

I am looking at putting some validation into this loop to make sure then entry is greater or equal to and less than or equal to 1024.

I have tried

```
if(scanf("%d", &records[*rCount].source) == 1 && &records[*rCount].source >= 1 && &records[r*Count].source <= 1024)
```

but that stops all entries working.

Below is the do while loop I am currently using thanks.

```
do{
        puts("What is the source of this packet?: ");
        if(scanf("%d", &records[*rCount].source) == 1){  //if correct insert the record at the index
            valid=1;                                //determined by rCount(the current     record count passed to addRecord
        }
        else{
            valid = 0;
            getchar();
            puts("\nNot a valid input");
        }

    }while(valid!=1);
```

Comment: Why is getchar here for?

Comment: `r*Count` is a typo, right?

Comment: @rullof Maybe to catch the newline (`'\n'`).

Comment: getchar stops a loop happening if the user enters a character.

Comment: @BitFiddlingCodeMonkey So he should use a loop: `while(getchar()!='\n');`

Comment: @BitFiddlingCodeMonkey that was a typo, thank you!

Comment: make sure to use getchar with a loop in case the user input a string

Comment: what type of loop would I use, just tried entering random numbers and text and it locks my programme up! Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are testing the **address** of the desired variable after you've read it.

You pass `&records[*rCount].source`, the address of `records[*rCount].source` (note the extra ampersand at the beginning) to scanf, so the function will save what it's reading from the standard input into this address. After that, you want to compare the variable value, not its address, against your limits.

Your corrected `if` will be:

```
if (scanf("%d", &records[*rCount].source) == 1
    && records[*rCount].source >= 1
    && records[*rCount].source <= 1024)
{
    // do stuff...
}
```

Comment: Yeah, probably. Thank  you Bit Fiddling Code Monkey for pointing it out and Michael Pryor for the edit.